# Unexpected '<' in php

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/u362231965/public_html/ucp/index.php on line 6

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$result= file_get_contents('ftp://160:654fearboss@149.202.249.9/scriptfiles/users/'.$num1.'_'.$num2.'.ini');
<pre>echo $result; </pre>
}
?>
<html><body>
<form action="#" method="post">
Num1:<input name="num1"><br>
Num2:<input name="num2">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body></html>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: change this <pre>echo $result; </pre> to this echo '<pre>'.$result.'</pre>';

Comment: It tells you what the problem is, and even where it is.

Answer (score 1):

You had a syntax error. Use this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$result= file_get_contents('ftp://160:654fearboss@149.202.249.9/scriptfiles/users/'.$num1.'_'.$num2.'.ini');
echo "<pre>".$result."</pre>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $result= file_get_contents('ftp://160:654fearboss@149.202.249.9/scriptfiles/users/'.$num1.'_'.$num2.'.ini');
    echo '<pre>'.$result.'</pre>';
}
?>
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code. This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem. The problem is that u are using html code inside php code, This is possible but you are doing it the whrong way.

```
<pre>echo $result; </pre>//this is the wrong way

echo '<pre>'.$result.'</pre>';//the good way
```

You can read this [how to use html inside php](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php)

Answer (score 0):

Why if i will go [link](http://continentalroleplay.esy.es/ucp/showit)
Which i made for testing with this code:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('ftp://160:654fearboss@149.202.249.9/scriptfiles/users/Isaiah_Calayan.ini');
?>
<h1>
  Remote Data
</h1>
<pre><?php echo $data; ?></pre>
```

Will show the data, but the [link](http://continentalroleplay.esy.es/ucp/index.php) will not show after submiting??